# Google MAP API V3 - Street View next panorama link

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

First of all. I was searching a long time, but I did not find what I want! How can I get next panorama? All what I know is need to get a panorama links. Links can get with `getLinks();`. I have read google's streetview manual, but I want to navigate with own navigation buttons not Google's!

Comment: Did you try reading the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/streetview#StreetViewPanoramas)?  There is an example that shows how to get the links data, each [link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#StreetViewLink) contains a pano "string" which is `A unique identifier for the panorama. This id is stable within a session but unstable across sessions`. Also there is a [getPanoramaById method in the google.maps.StreetViewService](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#StreetViewService).

Comment: However you don't need the getPanoramaById method for this use case...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Modified version of [Google Maps Javascript API v3 streetview-events example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/streetview-events) below which adds buttons to navigate the streetview panorama via the link.

in the global scope:

```
var panorama = null;
var links = null;

function setPano2link(i) {
  panorama.setPano(links[i].pano);
  panorama.setPov({heading:links[i].heading,pitch:0});
  panorama.setVisible(true);
}
```

Modify the "links_changed" event handler to add navigation buttons:

```
  google.maps.event.addListener(panorama, 'links_changed', function() {
      var linksTable = document.getElementById('links_table');
      while(linksTable.hasChildNodes()) {
        linksTable.removeChild(linksTable.lastChild);
      };
      links =  panorama.getLinks();
      for (var i in links) {
        var row = document.createElement('tr');
        linksTable.appendChild(row);
        var labelCell = document.createElement('td');
        labelCell.innerHTML = '<b>Link: ' + i + '</b>';
        var valueCell = document.createElement('td');
        valueCell.innerHTML = links[i].description;
        var btnCell = document.createElement('td');
        btnCell.innerHTML = '<input type="button" value="goto" onclick="setPano2link('+i+')"></input>';
        var panoIdCell = document.createElement('td');
        panoIdCell.innerHTML = links[i].pano;
        var headingCell = document.createElement('td');
        headingCell.innerHTML = links[i].heading;
        linksTable.appendChild(labelCell);
        linksTable.appendChild(valueCell);
        linksTable.appendChild(btnCell);
        linksTable.appendChild(panoIdCell);
        linksTable.appendChild(headingCell);
      }
  });
```

[working example](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_streetview-events_links.html)

Complete code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Street View events</title>
    <style>
      html, body, #map-canvas {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px
      }
    </style>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
<script>
var cafe = new google.maps.LatLng(37.869085,-122.254775);
var panorama = null;
var links = null;

function setPano2link(i) {
  panorama.setPano(links[i].pano);
  panorama.setPov({heading:links[i].heading,pitch:0});
  panorama.setVisible(true);
}

function initialize() {

  var panoramaOptions = {
    position: cafe,
    pov: {
      heading: 270,
      pitch: 0
    },
    visible: true
  };
  panorama = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(document.getElementById('pano'), panoramaOptions);

  google.maps.event.addListener(panorama, 'pano_changed', function() {
      var panoCell = document.getElementById('pano_cell');
      panoCell.innerHTML = panorama.getPano();
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(panorama, 'links_changed', function() {
      var linksTable = document.getElementById('links_table');
      while(linksTable.hasChildNodes()) {
        linksTable.removeChild(linksTable.lastChild);
      };
      links =  panorama.getLinks();
      for (var i in links) {
        var row = document.createElement('tr');
        linksTable.appendChild(row);
        var labelCell = document.createElement('td');
        labelCell.innerHTML = '<b>Link: ' + i + '</b>';
        var valueCell = document.createElement('td');
        valueCell.innerHTML = links[i].description;
        var btnCell = document.createElement('td');
        btnCell.innerHTML = '<input type="button" value="goto" onclick="setPano2link('+i+')"></input>';
        var panoIdCell = document.createElement('td');
        panoIdCell.innerHTML = links[i].pano;
        var headingCell = document.createElement('td');
        headingCell.innerHTML = links[i].heading;
        linksTable.appendChild(labelCell);
        linksTable.appendChild(valueCell);
        linksTable.appendChild(btnCell);
        linksTable.appendChild(panoIdCell);
        linksTable.appendChild(headingCell);
      }
  });


  google.maps.event.addListener(panorama, 'position_changed', function() {
      var positionCell = document.getElementById('position_cell');
      positionCell.firstChild.nodeValue = panorama.getPosition() + '';
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(panorama, 'pov_changed', function() {
      var headingCell = document.getElementById('heading_cell');
      var pitchCell = document.getElementById('pitch_cell');
      headingCell.firstChild.nodeValue = panorama.getPov().heading + '';
      pitchCell.firstChild.nodeValue = panorama.getPov().pitch + '';
  });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="pano" style="width: 45%; height: 100%;float:left"></div>
    <div id="panoInfo" style="width: 45%; height: 100%;float:left">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td><b>Position</b></td><td id="position_cell">&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><b>POV Heading</b></td><td id="heading_cell">270</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><b>POV Pitch</b></td><td id="pitch_cell">0.0</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><b>Pano ID</b></td><td id="pano_cell">&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <table id="links_table"></table>
    </table>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

- Go to this link: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/start
- Go to Google Maps and enter the street-view mode in your browser on the location you want
- Click on "**Share ..**"
- Search that **hyperlink-string** (CTRL-F/CMD-F) for "**!2e**", and **copy the string** from the first letter after "**!**" to the first letter after "**s**" in "**!1s**".

> ***Example:***
>
> **!1s**
>   -SWqF6BeQEBI%2FWBXbp08W9pI%2FAAAAAAAACRo%2F17TZj7OS3OMBBkrcNfZ45YlZxGydVryDwCLIB
>   **!2e**
>
> *If you have any "**%2F**" in the HTML-string, you need to replace them with "**/**". If you have "**-**"-symbol at start, you need to replace it with
>   "**F:-**"*.

- Now go back to the link given in the first bullet and click on the tab "**Show Street View or a custom panorama**"
- Past the **newly copied string** into the field "**Custom panorama ID:**" and press *enter*
- Now enter your API-key; remember to add the **right API-key** to your API-project that is made for panorama/street-view! ([Google Maps Embed API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/); you can add more than one key to your project) Click on "**Get Key**" if you have not already

---

And that is it!

*You will get a personal HTML-code you can past right in to you HTML-document. This is tested and works as of the date I wrote this.*